# Problem with an exchange integral

Tags: quantum-mechanics, wavefunction, integration

I'm reviewing the chapter on molecules from Gasiorowicz's Quantum Physics book (Ch. 20 of 1st edition) and it gets to a part where it solves the $H_2^+$ ion using the variational principle. There are two protons placed at positions $\pm$ **R**/2 (say, on the z-axis) and an electron at position **r**. The book uses two trial wave functions:
$$ \psi_1 (\boldsymbol{r,R}) = \left( \frac{1}{\pi a_0^3} \right)^{1/2} e^{-|\boldsymbol{r-R}/2|/a_0} $$

$$ \psi_2 (\boldsymbol{r,R}) = \left( \frac{1}{\pi a_0^3} \right)^{1/2} e^{-|\boldsymbol{r+R}/2|/a_0} $$

So I'm following along up to the point where it states the following result:
$$-\int d^3r \frac{|\psi_1 (\boldsymbol{r,R})|^2}{|\boldsymbol{r + R}/2|} = \frac{1}{a_0} e^{-2R/a_0}$$

which I'm pretty sure it's wrong because it's the wrong sign but I seem to be too rusty and can't work out the rest of the integral. I'd appreciate any help solving that integral.

Comment: I think the sign is indeed incorrect.

Comment: What does $d^{3}r$ denote? Spherical coordinates? What are the limits of integration - $a_0$? Maybe the negative sign should be on the other side of the equation?

Comment: The text doesn't specify how it integrates it. The sign is indeed incorrect, as pointed out in a previous comment. Since these are wave functions of the electron around two protons the integration must be over all space, right? I tried in cylindrical and failed, but I got confused with the spherical coord. integration.